# Parse Vector3 from a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a literal string that is like:

```
'(-0.0236, 0.0000, -31.2907)'
```

What is the best and fastest way to parse this into 3 floats, the issue I'm having is that because the floats can be any length precision I felt like a typical regex my have too many cases to consider with the positive and negative symbols as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another (kinda hacky) way of doing it:

```js
const SEPARATOR = /[^\d.+-]+/;

function parseFloats(str) {
    return str.split(SEPARATOR).filter(Boolean).map(parseFloat);
}

console.info(parseFloats('(-0.0236, 0.0000, -31.2907)'));
```

Instead of matching floats (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847324/778272), which I still prefer over this one because it's easier to understand), you match everything that is *not* a valid float character and use it as a separator. Then you pass it through a filter that gets rid of empty strings and finally parse each resulting float individually.

The magic `filter(Boolean)` works because empty strings evaluate to `false` when converted to a boolean. It's exactly the same as doing `filter(str => Boolean(str))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that format for all inputs, this is the best and fastest way to parse it, using string and array helpers:

```
let input = '(-0.0236, 0.0000, -31.2907)';
let result = input.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map(parseFloat);
console.log(result); //[-0.0236, 0, -31.2907]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so difficult to do it with a regex if you still wanted to, though:

```js
const FLOATS_REGEX = /[+-]?\d*\.\d*/g;

function parseFloats(str) {
    return str.match(FLOATS_REGEX).map(parseFloat);
}

console.info(parseFloats('(-0.0236, 0.0000, -31.2907)'));
```

Of course, matching floats can get [as complex as you want](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html). If your input pattern is well defined as it seems in your example, though, the simpler regex I suggested will be enough.